# Error when trying to get my current location using Bing Maps in a Windows Store App

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, bing-maps

I'm developing a Windows Store App where I'm using the Bing Maps control. I created a method that use the **Geolocator** and **GeoPosition** to get the users current position.

Also, I enabled the **location capability** from the manifiest file.

However, everytime when I run the App, the first time I click on the button to get the position I got the following error message: Access is denied. **(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))**.

When I click the second time in the same button to perform the same action, now the error messages disappear and the Bing Maps work properly showing me my current position. But, I'm a little concerned why I got the error messages always the firsr time I try to get the location.

Here are the two methods I execute to get the position:

```
private async Task SetMyLocation()
{
    var position = await GetCurrentPosition();
    if (position != null)
    {
        this.DataContext = position;

        this.myLocation = new Location(position.Latitude, position.Longitude);
        this.myMap.Center = this.myLocation;
        //this.myMap.ZoomLevel = 20;
        this.myMap.SetView(myLocation, 12, MapAnimationDuration.Default);

        this.AddMyLocationPushpin();
    }
}

private async Task<Position> GetCurrentPosition()
{
    try
    {
        Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();
        geolocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
        geolocator.MovementThreshold = 0;

        Geoposition location = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync(
            maximumAge: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
            timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
            );

        var postion = new Position
        {
            Latitude = location.Coordinate.Latitude,
            Longitude = location.Coordinate.Longitude
        };

        return postion;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
          . . .
          return null;
    }
}
```

Any suggestion, comment why I am getting the above error message? Any clue and/or solution would be OK?

Regards!

Comment: Which line does the exception get thrown from?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have allowed your app to access the user location. Open the Package manifest and go to the capabilities tab. Make sure the Location option is checked. Re-run your app, you will be prompted to allow the app to access your location, allow it. It should then work for you. You can find a blog post example on this here: http://www.bing.com/blogs/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2012/11/05/getting-started-with-bing-maps-windows-store-apps-native.aspx

Comment: I am facing same , if I allow permission to fetch location, and then suppose I switch off location settings and next time, it doesn't ask for permission and i also don't get any exception in that case. What I want to do is when location settings is off, i want to take my user to switch on location settings.